# After post back in MVC the JQuery DatePicker is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using MVC 1 Application where I have a view where I click a Save button and then server-side validation occurs, but after that my Date textbox does not work.

I have used the JQuery in MVC-View-page for a Date-textbox.

Can any one suggest me how to do that.

```
$(function () { 
    $("input[id*=DateFrom]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' }, 
    { changeMonth: true }, 
    { changeYear: true }); 
});

$(function () { 
    $("input[id*=DateTo]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' },
     { changeMonth: true },
     { changeYear: true }); 
});
```

Comment: You asked this same question 53 minutes ago. Why not modify the original question?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("#elementID").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jaskaran is correct but you are also using an invalid date format for jQuery UI:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
```

Should be this:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-M-y'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the MVC framework is irrelevant.  This is simply an HTML + Javascript issue.

You should ideally use a class name for the selector to apply the same datepicker functionality to multiple items. (unless you like writing the same code multiple times)

This code assumes that you have 2 inputs that look like this:

```
<input id="DateStart" type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input id="DateEnd" type="text" class="datepicker" />

$(function () { 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
       dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', 
       changeMonth: true, 
       changeYear: true 
    }); 
});
```

However, in order to diagnose your broken functionality...

Is this a full post back scenario, or a partial page AJAX update?

If it is an partial page Ajax update, then a likely cause of the problem could be that the input elements were removed, and then added back to the DOM after the partial page update.

The $(function() { ... }) is short for the document.ready callback.  That means that code is  only executed when the page is first loaded from the sever.

Any items added to the page after the page is loaded will not be affected by that code.

If you are doing a full page postback, then a likely cause for your problem is an error somewhere else in your javascript that is preventing the above code from being executed.

Have you tried using Firebug or any other web debugging utility to check for errors?